# What method is executed on Up button pressed

Tags: android, themes, back-button, oncreate

I implemented a `PreferenceActivity` and I allow the user to change the theme of the app. When the switch for that setting is flipped, initially nothing happens.

When the `Up button` is pressed, I am taken to the parent activity and it reloads the theme to use the new theme. However, if I'm still in the `SettingsActivity` and press the `Back` button, I get back to the MainActivity but the new theme is not applied. I suppose `MainActivity` doesn't reload `onCreate()` in that case.

I would like to `override the Back` button's behaviour in that `SettingsActivity` only and I know how to, but I don't know what method to execute in order to imitate the **Up button pressed** behaviour.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by the 'up button'? Is it a custom button you added?

Comment: It is the Up arrow which is in place of the Home button and when pressed takes you to the parent activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parent activity is something you have control over, just override the back button press. You can do it like so:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Replace "ParentActivity.class" with the name of your parent activity
    Intent parentIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ParentActivity.class);
    startActivity(parentIntent);
}
```

The above code should override the back button and give you the result you want.

Comment: haha wow thanks, I didn't realise it could be that simple...just a little offtopic clarification, when do we use finish(); together with startActivity? or do we only use finish() if we have a running activity behind this one?

Comment: Glad it helped! To answer your question, he `finish()` activity basically calls the `onDestroy()` method of the activity your Intent is going to. So you really don't need to use finish, because it would just stop the activity.

Comment: Unfortunately, this introduced a nasty bug. If I go from MainActivity into Settings and press the Back button, MainActivity is started again. If I press the Back button I'm taken to Settings again. Back button > Main Screen. Back Button>Settings Screen... and it's stuck in this loop.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Try overriding the MainActivity back button as well. That might stop the loop.